# ASP.NET - Output of angle brackets from a Web.sitemap file

Tags: asp.net, web.sitemap

I'm using a repeater to create a table of contents. The data comes from a Web.sitemap file.

One page in the site is about `List<T>`, so the sitemap node looks like this:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/path-to-page" title="List&lt;T&gt;"/>
```

The output for this particular node becomes:

```
<a href="/path-to-page">List<t></t></a>
```

The angle brackets are turned into a nonsense HTML tag.

I've tried two other character entities and neither one gets output as actual angle brackets. The output is the same as above.

```
title="List&#60;T&#62;"
title="List&#x3C;T&#x3E;"
```

Before I go in and figure out some sort of `string.Replace` solution or something, I was wondering if I'm missing some other way of putting angle brackets in the sitemap file so they're output properly.

P.S. the ItemTemplate just has:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was stepping through the results I realized that the angle brackets were not output in a weird way but actually as angle brackets, which is why they looked like HTML and produced the nonsense `<t>` tag.

I just had to `HtmlEncode` the output:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' 
    Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Title").ToString()) %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```